# Sliding arm problem, locking and singularity

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, moment

I posted a version of this earlier but I feel like my problem was not very clear so I hope that this explains what is so confusing here. Shown in the image is a view from above, of an arm that's driven by a pin-in-slot type joint, by a force $F_m$. The intended motion is for it to move straight (vertically downwards) along that slot, shown by the dotted lines. The arm is then also experiencing an external force, $F_p$. This of course makes the arm want to rotate about the pivot in the pin, however it is constrained by what is shown here as a wall on the left side of the image. Therefore it rotates a very small amount before there is a contact point at the corner shown (in real life this is 3D, extending out of the page, hence the strange contact corner, however it is modelled as a 2D rigid body here). The small angle means I'm treating all forces and dimensions as if this angle was zero. I am trying to work out the required force, $F_m$ that is needed to move this arm (and overcome the external force, and friction with the wall), assuming all dimensions and $F_p$ are known.

The bottom half of the page shows my attempt at working this out: I have added a reaction force and friction force at the contact point with the wall, and solved for moments and vertical forces. However, the result I get from this seems wrong for a couple of reasons - the force is negative, and also there is a singularity at a certain value of $\mu$ (the friction coefficient at the wall).

Does anyone have any ideas about this strange behaviour and about whether I'm missing any forces/moments that are acting here? It is a very strange situation I haven't encountered before.

Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: I recreated the situation using cardboard, and found that it does indeed jam when a force $F_m$ is applied. I'm therefore thinking that maybe the answer I'm getting is correct - see this plot of $\mu$ against $F_m$ for small $\mu$:

[image]

As you can see, the required force increases a lot up to the point of the 'singularity', after which it says that $F_m$ would have to be negative, which I'm taking as basically it will never work. Therefore, the situation would only work if $\mu$ is very small, and it makes sense it didn't work with cardboard, and in reality it would either need bearings there or something else to stop rotation. Is a relationship like this logical physically?

Comment: This is a statically indeterminate problem as the two contacts fight each other, and thus cannot be solved with the rigid body assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem that can be solved by considering the several regimes that are found in the limits of the two applied force $F_p$ and $F_m$.  Also, critical here is to treat the frictional force $F_r$ appropriately and realize that it's not always equal to its limiting value $\mu R$.  Here's a more complete explanation:

For the frictional force $F_r$, note that it is not a force that drives motion of the system, but only stops motion of the system.  Maybe you know this, but it's not clear from your post, but if you put it into an equation as $F_r = \mu R$ where it looks like it drives the motion of the system you are *implicitly solving for a limit where the frictional force is just barely able to keep the system static*.

To get a bit more intuition on $F_r$ *vs* its limiting case, consider, for example, the situation where $F_p = F_m$ and are both large.  Therefore, $F_r = 0$ because there's no net force driving the system to move.  But then, why won't it rotate?  It won't rotate because the corner will be forced into the wall, increasing $R$ until a counter rotation force is created to give zero net torque, that is, $F_p d_p = R d_R $ from the first equation.  This $R$ then only describes what $F_r$ could be as a result of force $R$, and in this case only the limit described by $\overline{F_r} = \mu R$ (where here I've used the overbar to specify $F_r$ at this limit).

With that out of the way, consider the case where $F_p = 0$ and $F_r = F_m < \overline{F_r}$, so the system is static and not at the limit of the frictional force.  Here, then, note that $R = F_r d_y / d_R$.  Now consider a second system with everything identical, but where $d_{R,2}$ is smaller than $d_R$.  For this second system, $F_{r,2} = F_r$, but $R_2$ will be larger, and it can be dramatically larger depending on how small $d_{R,2}$ is.  Clearly, then, since $R$ can be infinitely large depending on how small $d_R$ is, so $\overline{F_r} = \mu R$ can also be infinitely large.  ($F_p$ just adds or subtracts from this depending on sign and direction, but the basic logic is the same.)

Therefore, a reasonable and finite $F_m$ can produce a very large $\overline{F_r}$ due to the levering of $d_y / d_R$.

On whether this system can "lock", that is, be in a state where increasing $F_m$ won't move the system, note that if $F_p=0$ so $F_r = F_m$, then $\overline{F_r} = \mu F_m d_y/d_R$, so $\overline{F_r}$ just scales with $F_m$, and therefore increasing $F_m$ won't move the system either, that is, the system is locked.  Note that in this limit where $F_p$ is small relative to the other forces (because the system is locked so $F_m$ can increase indefinitely), then $\overline{F_r} \approx F_m$ so that $1 = \mu d_y/d_R$.  That is, the system is in a locking regime when $\mu d_y/d_R \ge 1$, so, for  example, when $\mu d_y/d_R < 1$, $\overline{F_r}<F_m$ at large $F_m$ so the system can always move as $F_m$ becomes large enough.

Also, though, note that for any value of $F_m$ (and all the other parameters), if $F_p$ pulls downward, it can always be large enough to overcome $F_r$ and allow the system to move, and if it pushes upward, it can always force the system to not move.

Therefore, I suggest conceptualizing this in the following way:
 **There are two parameter regimes, "locking" and "not locking" corresponding to the behavior at large $F_m$ and delineated by $\mu d_y/d_R = 1$ (specifically, corresponding to whether $F_m$ will force the system to move), and at any specific $F_m$ where $F_p$ is relevant, $F_p$ can allow the system to move or force it to stop based on $F_p$'s direction and value.**

This is consistent with my experience using this type of system, where one has to operate them gently, because they can fall into a behavior where the system locks up (and increasing $F_m$ doesn't help), and that when they do lock up, pulling down via $F_p$ frees them up, and an easy way to stop a moving system is pushing up on $F_p$.

For the "singularity" question, note that $F_p$ changes sign depending on the parameters (for some parameters $F_p$ is aligned with $F_r$ and for others it's aligned against $F_r$); that is, for any parameters, $F_p$ can have a range of values, but only one value where $F_r = \overline{F_r}$ and that value of $F_p$ changes sign and goes through $0$ depending on the parameters.  Since you've written your solution in the form $F_m = F_p X$, $X$ has to be very large when $F_p$ is near zero, etc, for this formulation to work.  But this doesn't mean that any forces become infinite, etc.  The reason this occurs at the delineating value $\mu d_y/d_R = 1$ is that your formulation as a product of $F_p$ forces an infinity when $F_p =0$, but this is also in coincidence with $F_p \approx 0$ (*i.e.*, $F_p$ is small relative to the other forces) which also happens to be the situation for large $F_m$, which defines the locking condition.

Comment: Hi, we've noticed that you have made a large number of minor edits to this post. Please be mindful that every edit bumps the post in the "active" tab of the site and try to make your edits substantial. If you foresee improving this post repeatedly, maybe collect several edits and make them in one go instead of submitting them individually.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123994/discussion-on-answer-by-tom10-sliding-arm-problem-locking-and-singularity).